# memcached: how to clear all keys with "flushable" in the name

Tags: ruby, memcached

I'm using Memcached 1.4.14-0ubuntu9.3 with a ruby project.  I want a way to clear all keys that have the string "flushable" in them.  The only way I've come up with so far is a script which telnets onto the port to read the keys:  I can then grep those for the substring, and call an individual `delete` call for each.  But, this feels rather inelegant to say the least.

Is there a way to do it more elegantly within my connection from Ruby?  I access memcache via an object called CACHE.

Comment: Hard to say without some code to see but if your hash is called memhash: memhash.each { |key, value| memhash.delete(key) if key.include?('flushable') }

Comment: Memcached doesn't have an `each` method that works like this, as far as I can see.  It doesn't store everything as a hash, it's via its own internal (black box) workings.

Comment: @Mark, if it were a simple hash, it would be better to use [Hash#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject) (or [Hasj#reject!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-reject-21) if you want to mutate the hash) so you aren't deleting elements of the hash (key-value pairs) that are being enumerated.